# GET api data using curl command

Tags: javascript, api, curl, get

I am trying to get some data from public api's using curl:

```
curl --request GET 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=37.3565982&lon=-121.9689848&units=imperial' \
--header 'X-Api-Key: x-api-‘key \
--data 'output_format=csv' \
> save_file.csv
```

and if I am running the command in terminal is returning the output and everything is working just fine but if I am trying to add an extra parameter to download the result in a .csv format, is generating the file but the format inside is wrong, I mean is not added as a table format but more like a array of objects `[{}, {}, {}]` and so on.

It is possible to run a curl command and get the data in a csv format ?

Answer (score 0):

`--data` is how you add body data to a POST request. You are making a GET request.

The [api documentation](https://openweathermap.org/current) for the webservice you are using says:

> mode  optional    Response format. Possible values are xml and html. If you don't use the mode parameter format is JSON by default. Learn more

So to get something other than JSON back from the server, you need to put `mode=something` in the query string and only XML and HTML are options.

It is not `output_format`.

It does not go in the body.

CSV is not an option.

---

If you want to put that data into CSV format, then you'll need to transform it locally. The data format described in the documentation does not look like it lends itself to the 2D data structures described by CSV so you'll have to make decisions about how to transform it.

You've tagged this [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) so you could pipe the output of `curl` into a program you run with Node.js which [parses the JSON](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/javascript-conventions/what-is-json/#encoding-and-decoding), restructures it however you like, and then uses a module like [papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse) to convert it to JSON.

Comment: ok, so basically I am unable to do that in a single curl command :|

Comment: Well. Yes. curl makes HTTP requests. You are dependant on the service you are making the request to to do what you want with the request.

Comment: that's a strange API, why isn't `json` a valid value for mode? but i'm asking the wrong guy here, unless you're an openwheatermap dev :P

Comment: @hanshenrik — No idea. I would have designed `json` and nothing to be equivalent rather than having nothing as the only value meaning JSON.